# Integrating SMS api with woocommerce , Not sending messages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm integrating SMS API with WooCommerce to send automatic order updates to customers mobiles whenever the make any purchase on site.

below is my code for the same

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);
function custom_process_order($billing_phone)
{
$username = "my username";
$hash = "d761fbd7bd31c5eeec2a5b2556d6b9d3b1a1ae51";
//Multiple mobiles numbers separated by comma
$mobileNumber = "$billing_phone";


$senderId = "ORNGMT";
$message = urlencode("Dear Customer");
$postData = array(
    'hash' => $hash,
    'mobiles' => $$billing_phone,
    'message' => $message,
    'sender' => $senderId,

);
$url='http://api.textlocal.in/send/?';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData
    //,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
}
```

is it correct ? 
I've added this code to functions.php page

my sms gateway provider has sent me below example code to send sms with PHP

```
<?php
// Authorisation details.
$username = "your login id";
$hash = "your hash key";

// Configuration variables. Consult http://api.textlocal.in/docs for more info.
$test = "0";

// Data for text message. This is the text message data.
$sender = "API Test"; // This is who the message appears to be from.
$numbers = "44777000000"; // A single number or a comma-seperated list of numbers
$message = "This is a test message from the PHP API script.";
// 612 chars or less
// A single number or a comma-seperated list of numbers
$message = urlencode($message);
$data = "username=".$username."&hash=".$hash."&message=".$message."&sender=".$sender."&numbers=".$numbers."&test=".$test;
$ch = curl_init('http://api.textlocal.in/send/?');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch); // This is the result from the API
curl_close($ch);
```

?>

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What part is failing? Have you done any kind of step-through to find the point of failure? Right now you're asking us to debug your code for you.

Comment: It's not sending messages.

Comment: Still advise you to step-through the code and echo/var_dump various parts so you can see where it is failing.  PS- I would also recommend taking a look at [wp_remote_post()]https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post)

Comment: For example, just on first glance I can see `$mobileNumber = "$billing_phone";` on one line and then `'mobiles' => $$billing_phone,`. are you sure you are passing valid phone numbers in the format accepted by the API?

Comment: No, Mam! I'm not sure about it. :( http://api.textlocal.in/docs/sendsms > this is the api what I'm using. I don't have any prior knowledge about this so googling it from last few days.

Comment: You can also use [hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/) to run sample API calls which will help you see any errors. This is a little broad for StackOverflow. I would suggest you hire a developer.

Comment: Thank for your advice. I will hire a developer ! Can you guide me how much i should pay to developer for this task?

Comment: Hard to say. For example, for just this function I'd probably charge around $250 usd, assuming I didn't run into any problems with the API, but it looks relatively well-documented. To build it out into a complete plugin it could be a lot more. Would any existing plugins such as [SMS notification](https://www.woothemes.com/products/sms-notifications) work where you are?

Comment: I'm getting error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token r"

Answer (score 3):

Integrating message API for each event will be difficult and you need to customize the at the code level.

You can use a popular SMSplugin for wordpress woocommerce

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-apg-sms-notifications/

Just you need to configure this plugin from woocommerce Admin login and it will send sms notifications automatically. We are using it with [Spring Edge sms gateway](http://springedge.com).. Working Good.

Answer (score 1):

Tested and working
Custom api Integration with Woocommerce wordpress

Ufone pakistan sms integration with woocommerce wordpress

if you are looking for integration with ufone pakistan sms api bsms ufone pakistan service provider with woocommerce wordpress then use the following code in your functions file

sms api integration ufone bsms with wordpress woocommerce thanks to the author on this page Integrating custom SMS API with woocommerce

```
//add this line for calling your function on creation of order in woocommerce 
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'custom_func', 10, 3);

function custom_func ($order_id) {

$order_details = new WC_Order($order_id);

//fetch all required fields
$billing_phone = $order_details->get_billing_phone();
$billing_name = $order_details->get_billing_first_name();
$billing_last_name = $order_details->get_billing_last_name();
$total_bill = $order_details->get_total();

$textmessage = rawurlencode("Dear $billing_name, Thank you for your order. Your order #$order_id is being processed. Please wait for confirmation call Total Bill = $total_bill");

// Now put HTTP ufone BSMS API URL
$url = "https://bsms.ufone.com/bsms_v8_api/sendapi-0.3.jsp?id=msisdn&message=$textmessage&shortcode=SHORTCODE&lang=English&mobilenum=$billing_phone&password=password&messagetype=Nontransactional";

// NOW WILL CALL FUNCTION CURL  
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$err = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $order_id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$billingphone in your function is ID. Try this below code. It works

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);
function custom_process_order($order_id) {
//Lets get data about the order made
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

//Now will fetch customer/buyer id here
$customer_id = $order->user_id;

//now finally we fetch phone number 
$billing_phone = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', true );

// Now put your HTTP SMS API URL . I PUT WHICH WE ARE USING
$jsonurl = "http://tsms.thirdeyegoa.com/api/sendmsg.php?user=USERNAME&pass=PASSWORD&sender=MYSENDERID&phone=".$billing_phone."&priority=ndnd&stype=normal&text=MY MESSAGE TO CUSTOMER.";

// NOW WILL CALL FUNCTION CURL  
$json = curl($jsonurl);

return $order_id;
}
```

Same you can do for Order Completed too with respective hook.

Comment: Thanks for reply, can you help with my api? It's not working.

Comment: your api may be different regarding that contact your sms provider. but this is how you can grab the billing phone number of user and send them sms. If you want sms package with easy api contact the sms provider. this is the same way i used and its working very good.

You can use it for order complete, processing, payment complete etc hooks. put this code in functions.php you can dump results and check you will get it.

Comment: I've posted example of code which they have provided me.

Comment: Ok then Check Curl. Whether service provider API Url needs POST or just hitting the link

Comment: then please follow to their documentation of using sms api. thanks

Comment: I'm getting this error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token r"

Answer (score 0):

i write this piece of code and it is working.

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed','payment_complete');
  function payment_complete($order_id)
{

$order=new Wc_order($order_id);
$order_meta = get_post_meta($order_id);
$shipping_first_name = $order_meta['_shipping_first_name'][0];
$phone=$order_meta['_billing_phone'][0];
$first_name=$order->billing_first_name;
$last_name=$order->billing_last_name;
$name=$first_name."".$last_name;
$mobile=$order->billing_mobile;
$items = $order->get_items();
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
$product_name = $item['name'];
$product_id = $item['product_id'];
$product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];
$time=$item['timings'];
$slot=$item['time_slot'];
$qty= $item['qty'];
$date=$item['tour_date'];
}
$text="your message here";
$data="user=username&pass=password&sender=sendername&phone=".$phone."&priority=ndnd&stype=normal&text=".$text;
$ch = curl_init('http://bhashsms.com/api/sendmsg.php?');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
 echo $result; 
curl_close($ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am from Textlocal. Let me help you out with the code.

Firstly the error that you are getting - 'Unexpected Token' is generally due to an invalid JSON response. If you are unaware of the source of the issue, I would suggest you to look in the Javascript console in the Dev section (triggering the error). For reference, you can check Mike's blog out [here](https://mikejolley.com/2015/11/12/debugging-unexpected-token-in-woocommerce-2-4/).

In the code you have shared, Textlocal API is not receiving the parameters that are mandatory for a successful POST call. You can rephrase your function like this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);
function custom_process_order($order_id) {

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$customer_id = $order->user_id; 
$billing_phone = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', true );

$data="username=USERNAME&hash=hash&sender=ORNGMT&numbers=".$billing_phone."&message=MY MESSAGE TO CUSTOMER.";
$jsonurl = curl_init('https://api.textlocal.in/send?');

$json = curl($jsonurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($json);
echo $result; 
curl_close($json);

return $order_id;
}
```

If you need any further assistance, please reach out to our support team (support@textlocal.in)