# How to add a javascript api to wordpress function.php

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I'm trying to add an sms api to Wordpress which sends an order confirmation message using Woocommerce hooks. After some research, I found the following code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416399/integrating-sms-api-with-woocommerce-not-sending-messages) which works the same way.

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);
function custom_process_order($order_id) {
//Lets get data about the order made
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

//Now will fetch customer/buyer id here
$customer_id = $order->user_id;

//now finally we fetch phone number 
$billing_phone = get_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', true );

// Now put your HTTP SMS API URL . I PUT WHICH WE ARE USING
$jsonurl = "http://tsms.thirdeyegoa.com/api/sendmsg.php?user=USERNAME&pass=PASSWORD&sender=MYSENDERID&phone=".$billing_phone."&priority=ndnd&stype=normal&text=MY MESSAGE TO CUSTOMER.";

// NOW WILL CALL FUNCTION CURL  
$json = curl($jsonurl);

return $order_id;
}
```

The Api Code my sms gateway provided is

```
 // Include provided Java Script 

<script language="javascript" src="https://domainapi.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script language="javascript">

// Replace your API key at below line 

var apikey = 'ABCDEFGH1234567890abcdefghQWERTY123='; 

// Form your data object 

var mail_details = { email : 'John.Doe@foo.com', msgid : '82', listname : '', prefix : '', firstname : 'John', middlename : '', lastname : 'Doe', telephone : '', address : '', city : '', state : '', pincode : '', country : '', mobile : '9999999999', designation : '', company : '', companyphone : '', birthdate : '', anniversary : '', extra1 : '', extra2 : '' } 

call_api(apikey, 'sendSingleSMS', mail_details, function(response) { document.getElementById('show').innerHTML=response; });</script>
```

Please tell me how to integrate this API in the above script for Wordpress.

Comment: Please explain more your question. You just paste code in functions.php and provide javascript code and I don't see anything 2 file working together?

Comment: Hi., Thanks for looking into it....I'm trying to add [this](http://docs.juvlon.com/api/sendTransSms.html#sendSingleSMS) api to my Woocommerce store when an order is complete. Could you please tell me how can I do that ? @Quỳnh Nguyễn

Comment: It is how the sms gateway documentation suggests. Please check [this api documentation](http://docs.juvlon.com/api/sendTransSms.html#sendSingleSMS) @LoicTheAztec

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I'll explain. I'm trying to add a functionality to my Woocommerce store which sends order confirmation sms to the user when an order is placed. The SMS gateway I've opted provides a js API which I can use to achieve the same. [Here is their documentation](http://docs.juvlon.com/api/sendTransSms.html#sendSingleSMS). Can you please tell me how can I integrate this API to my Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you are trying to blend your API's script into the "WordPress way" and load some data from WooCommerce's order. First, you'd want to register your scripts in your main plugin file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_38554614_enqueue_scripts' );
function so_38554614_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_register_script( 'your-api', 'https://domainapi.js', array(), '1.0', true );
    wp_register_script( 'your-script', 'path-to-your-script.js', array('your-api'), '1.0', true );
}
```

And then you'll want to load them on the payment complete page. You will also want to take advantage of `wp_localize_script()` to pass some variables to the script.

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);
function custom_process_order($order_id) {
    //Lets get data about the order made
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    wp_enqueue_script('your-api');
    wp_enqueue_script('your-script');

    $l18n = array( 'mail_details'=> 
                array( 
                    email' => $order->billing_email,
                   'msgid' => 82,
                   'listname' => '',
                   'firstname' => $order->billing_first_name,
                   'middlename' => '',
                   'lastname' => $order->billing_last_name,
                   'telephone' => $order->billing_phone,
                   'address'= >$order->billing_address_1 . ' ' . $order->billing_address_2,
                   'city' => $order->billing_city,
                   'state' => $order->billing_state,
                   'pincode' => '',
                   'country' => $order->billing_country,
                   'mobile' => $order->billing_phone
                   'designation' => '',
                   'company' => $order->billing_company,
                   'companyphone' => '',
                   'birthdate' => '',
                   'anniversary' => '',
                   'extra1' => '',
                   'extra2' => '' 
                ),
                'apikey' => 'ABCDEFGH1234567890abcdefghQWERTY123=' );

    wp_localize_script( 'your-script', 'Your_JS_Object', $l18n );

    wp_localize_script()

    return $order_id;
}
```

And finally, your javascript file, stored somewhere in your plugin. It takes advantage of the javascript object `Your_JS_Object` which was created by `wp_localize_script()`:

```
// Java Script path-to-your-script.js
call_api( Your_JS_Object.apikey, 'sendSingleSMS', Your_JS_Object.mail_details, function(response) { document.getElementById('show').innerHTML=response; });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot., Can you please tell me what  'wp_register_script( 'your-script', 'path-to-your-script.js', array('your-api'), '1.0', true );' this code is for in the plugin registration? @helgatheviking

Comment: Please see the documentation for [`wp_register_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/). This is the correct way to load scripts from your plugin.

Comment: I'm just getting started with Wordpress and can you please tell me in which Wordpress files should I place all the above three pieces of codes ? @helgatheviking

Comment: I would create a plugin. Here's a good [tutorial](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin). As mentioned, the javascript would be in it's own file.